# Variable not updating in Switch case

Tags: java

```
public class Tester{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int upNext = 1332;
        switch (upNext) {
            case 1:
                upNext -= 1;
                case 3:
                    upNext -= 2;
                case 13:
                    upNext -= 3;
            case 1332:
                    upNext++;
            System.out.println(upNext);
            case 1333:
                upNext--;
        System.out.println(upNext);
        }   
        System.out.println(upNext);
    }
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
1333
1332
1332
```

I am unable to understand, why this is happening. I am new to programming. Can you please throw some light on the concept behind this?

Comment: you forgot your break statements. if you don't add those, all the following cases will be executed as well, waterfall wise

Comment: [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/switch_statement_in_java.htm)'s a related explanation on the subject

Comment: what is you r question ,, what you want , the Value it is updating one time plus and one time minus